# TypeError: Only absolute URLs are supported in Nextjs while deploying to azure

Tags: reactjs, azure, next.js

Running perfectly in local and Vercel but not deploy into the azure
[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you show us the code for `getStaticPaths` in `/pages/blog/[slug]` and the `getAllPostsWithSlug` function? It may be related to an environment variable not being set properly.

Comment: Slug.js page https://pastebin.pl/view/22202b11

Comment: While providing a link is fine, your question should be self-contained and preferably not rely on external resources to be answered. Please add the relevant code to the question. Also, please add the `getAllPostsWithSlug`'s code as well.